# Warnings with Smarty after upgrade to PHP 7.0.8

Tags: php, smarty

After upgrading Plesk and PHP to the version 7.0.8, I'm getting the following warning when using Smarty.

> PHP Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Smarty_Compiler has a deprecated constructor in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/Smarty/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 35

Here the file mentioned in the warning:

```
/*
 * @link http://smarty.php.net/
 * @author Monte Ohrt <monte at ohrt dot com>
 * @author Andrei Zmievski <andrei@php.net>
 * @version 2.6.20
 * @copyright 2001-2005 New Digital Group, Inc.
 * @package Smarty
 */

/* $Id: Smarty_Compiler.class.php 2773 2008-08-12 18:17:51Z Uwe.Tews $ */

/**
 * Template compiling class
 * @package Smarty
 */
class Smarty_Compiler extends Smarty {
```

I need help to understand the problem and how to fix it, is it relative to Smarty or fixable on my end?

Comment: share more information please like what's your php version now? and share  the full error message.

Comment: AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Smarty_Compiler has a deprecated constructor in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/Smarty/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 35\n'

Comment: Runing PHP version 7.0.8

Comment: I edited the title of your question to include more informations about your warning, like the PHP version you just updated to. I added to the question all new informations you provided in the comments too and improved the formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of `PHP 7.0.x`, `PHP 4 style constructors (methods that have the same name as the class they are defined in)` are deprecated, and will be removed in the future. PHP 7 will emit `E_DEPRECATED` if a PHP 4 constructor is the only constructor defined within a class. Classes that implement a __construct() method are unaffected.

So, there's two solution:

1. You can turn off the deprecated warning message by adding this on your code:
   `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);`
2. Edit the `Smarty_Compiler.class.php`file and change the method name `Smarty_Compiler()` to `__construct()`

Comment: class Smarty_Compiler extends Smarty {

    // internal vars
    /**#@+
     * @access private
     */

    /**#@-*/
    /**
     * The class constructor.
     */
    function Smarty_Compiler()
    {

Comment: yes, rename `function Smarty_Compiler()` to `function __construct()`.

Comment: it works. I changed it in two files: Smarty_Compiler... and Smarty...